# Show multiple statuses/state on a list item

Tags: android, lists, states

Currently, I am working on a feature for a mobile forms application where users can send data via SMS and Internet. What I need to accomplish is a way to display both the internet and sms submission state on a list item in an user friendly manner. What I am seeking is a bit of advice on the best practices for presenting the primary elements of the list item which would be the title and then secondary items such as states. Currently this is how the screen looks.

[image]

In terms of showing both statuses I was thinking of simply putting a divider below the existing status shown here. i.e "Failed on xyz" so I would put the status underneath and each status would have the icon representing the transport before it. Any thoughts or ideas are welcome.

Comment: How much does your average user need to know about the status? Do they need to know the time date and reason up front or do they just need to know if it's successful? You could also look at how Facebook Messenger and Whatsapp use icons to show message statuses.

Comment: It's critical for them when they are in this mode because they are basically enumerators/field workers. So the data they submitting is very time sensitive but the environment they are working in might be challenging connectivity wise (eg. users in Africa, Brazil, Caribbean)  so they need to get a good idea of the how the data they are collecting has been submitted.

Comment: You can extend height of cards so your design "breaths more". Users scroll either way. For statuses you can them separate them with more space, ad X icon for failed, and check icon for sucess status. Also you can paint them red and green. Should be sufficient visual clue for user.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide 2 view modes for the user to either see notifications as they come up, or within the context of the their group. Also, the icons for SMS vs Wireless can use conventional ones from the phone. SMS can be 4G or LTE.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEPzt2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of organizing the statuses by date theb status makes sense here.  Seeing the status for August 19 tucked in between the two August 14 statuses could be confusing.

Would the user want to know the most recent status at the top?

Comment: So there would just be two statuses being shown, one for each protocol. So SMS would have a status for itself and Internet another. Each of these statuses would be updated by individual based on what happens in the background.